# SDL code compiles but the window doesn't show up

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

The window was opening properly but after changing some variable names it simple doesn't show up. I can't undo the changes because I've tried restarting the PC.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Professional, msvc2012 plus SDL2 and SDL_Image.
Don't know if that matters but the laptop's configurations are: i7, 8gb ram, windows 8.1 pro, gtx 850M 4gb vram.

Here's the code:

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "SDL.h"

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    bool init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags);
    void render();
    void update();
    void handleEvents();
    void clean();
    bool running() { return gameRunning; }
private:
    SDL_Window * window;
    SDL_Renderer * renderer;
    SDL_Rect * player;

    bool gameRunning;
};


#endif
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{
    player->x = 0;
    player->y = 0;
    player->w = 32;
    player->h = 32;
}

Game::~Game()
{

}

bool Game::init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, int flags)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
        if (window != 0)
        {
            renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
            if (renderer != 0)
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
            }
            else { return false; }
        } else { return false; }
    } else { return false; }

    gameRunning = true;

    return true;
}

void Game::render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer); 

    //SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &*player);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void Game::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            gameRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

void Game::clean()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void Game::update()
{

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Game* game;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    game = new Game();
    game->init("Lumia", 100, 100, 640, 480, 0);
    while (game->running())
    {
        game->handleEvents();
        game->update();
        game->render();
    }
    game->clean();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check if `Game::init` is returning false, then make sure your application's entry point is `WinMain`. If you created the project as a console application, it won't be.

Comment: I created as an empty project, and the subsystem is set to Windows.

Comment: Build a debug version, start a debugger, set a breakpoint on the first statement in the `main` function, run the program. If the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint then you know your `main` function is not called. If it stops, then step through the code, line by line, to see what happens.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the program starts, but nothing happens, to stop the program I had to force quit it through Debug >> Stop Debugging

Comment: Then that means your `main` function isn't called. IIRC the SDL2 library have its *own* `main` function which apparently overrides your.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how to fix that?

Comment: I found out that changing the player.x, .y , .h, .w to comments makes the window show up, it seems like the program gets stuck in these lines, how to fix that?

Comment: You should start using some form of source control. Then you could easily go back without having to rely on undo buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class `Game`, `player` is a pointer.

When you do

```
Game::Game()
{
    player->x = 0;
    player->y = 0;
    player->w = 32;
    player->h = 32;
}
```

the pointer `player` was never initialized, it doesn't point to a valid object so you can't dereference it or that's undefined behavior (and probably why your debugger stops).

You need to construct `player` first before you try assigning to it, just like you constructed a new `Game` in main before trying to use it.